# X11 Desktop Pager

Tags: c, x11

This is a simple desktop pager for UNIX/X11 environments. More information in the manual:

```
PAGINATOR(1)                General Commands Manual               PAGINATOR(1)

NAME
     paginator - X11 desktop pager

SYNOPSIS
     paginator [-w] [-c corner] [-g geometry] [-l layout] [-o orientation]

DESCRIPTION
     paginator is a desktop pager for X11 that provides to the user a GUI
     interface to change the current desktop or the current window with
     mouse's button 1.

     The options are as follows:

     -c corner
          Specify the corner of the pager in which the first desktop should be
          placed.  The argument for this option must be TL, TR, BL, or BR
          (top-left, top-right, bottom-left, or bottom-right, respectively).
          If not provided, the starting corner will be top-left.

     -g geometry
          Specify a size for the pager window.  The argument for this option
          must be a geometry specification recognized by XParseGeometry(1) If
          not provided, the window size will be computed from the pager
          layout, the number of desktops and the size of the screen.

     -l layout
          Specify the layout of the pager.  The argument for this option must
          be in the format NCOLSxNROWS, where NCOLS is the number of columns
          in the pager, and NROWS is the number of rows in the pager.  If not
          specified, the number of columns will be 2, and the number of rows
          will be computed from the number of desktops.

     -o orientation
          Specify the orientation of the desktops on the pager.  The argument
          for this option must be H, or V (horizontal or vertical,
          respectively).  If not provided, the starting corner will be
          horizontal.

     -w   Start in the withdrawn mode.  This makes paginator work like a
          dockapp.

     Paginator only works in cooperation with EWMH-compliant window managers.
     In particular, with window managers which set the
     _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING and _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS properties.

ENVIRONMENT
     The following environment variables affect the execution of paginator

     DISPLAY
          The display to start paginator on.

SEE ALSO
     X(1)

BUGS
     Paginator does not move client windows by moving the mini windows in the
     pager.  It does not show the icon name nor the icon of the client windows
     in the pager.  It also does not have an option to present itself to the
     window manager as a panel/bar.  Those features may be added in a later
     version.

                                                                  PAGINATOR(1)
```

The code is split in `config.h`, containing default configuration, and `paginator.c`, containing the actual code.

config.h:

```c
struct Config config = {
    /* number of columns and rows, if 0 they are computed from the number of desktops */
    .ncols = 2,
    .nrows = 0,

    /* desktop orientation */
    .orient = _NET_WM_ORIENTATION_HORZ,

    /* starting corner on the desktop grid */
    .corner = _NET_WM_TOPLEFT,

    /* colors */
    .windowcolors[STYLE_ACTIVE][COLOR_BACKGROUND]   = "#729FCF",
    .windowcolors[STYLE_ACTIVE][COLOR_BORDER]       = "#204A87",
    .windowcolors[STYLE_INACTIVE][COLOR_BACKGROUND] = "#555753",
    .windowcolors[STYLE_INACTIVE][COLOR_BORDER]     = "#888A85",
    .desktopselbg    = "#2E3436",
    .desktopbg       = "#121212",
    .separator       = "#888A85",
};
```

paginator.c:

```c
#include <err.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Xproto.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>

#define PROGNAME        "Paginator"
#define MAX_DESKTOPS    100             /* maximum number of desktops */
#define DEF_WIDTH       125             /* default width for the pager */
#define DEF_NCOLS       2               /* default number of columns */
#define SEPARATOR_SIZE  1               /* size of the line between minidesktops */
#define RESIZETIME      64              /* time to redraw containers during resizing */
#define PAGER_ACTION    ((long)(1 << 14))
#define SEPARATOR(x)    ((x) * SEPARATOR_SIZE)

/* colors */
enum {
    COLOR_BACKGROUND,
    COLOR_BORDER,
    COLOR_LAST
};

/* decoration style */
enum {
    STYLE_ACTIVE,
    STYLE_INACTIVE,
    STYLE_LAST
};

/* atoms */
enum {
    WM_DELETE_WINDOW,
    _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW,
    _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING,
    _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP,
    _NET_WM_DESKTOP,
    _NET_DESKTOP_LAYOUT,
    _NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP,
    _NET_MOVERESIZE_WINDOW,
    _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS,
    _NET_WM_STATE,
    _NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN,

    ATOM_LAST,
};

/* orientation */
enum Orientation {
    _NET_WM_ORIENTATION_HORZ = 0,
    _NET_WM_ORIENTATION_VERT = 1,
};

/* starting corner */
enum StartingCorner {
    _NET_WM_TOPLEFT     = 0,
    _NET_WM_TOPRIGHT    = 1,
    _NET_WM_BOTTOMRIGHT = 2,
    _NET_WM_BOTTOMLEFT  = 3,
};

/* draw context */
struct DC {
    unsigned long windowcolors[STYLE_LAST][COLOR_LAST];
    unsigned long desktopselbg;
    unsigned long desktopbg;
    unsigned long separator;
    GC gc;
};

/* mini-desktop geometry */
struct Desktop {
    Window miniwin;
    int x, y, w, h;
};

/* client info */
struct Client {
    Window clientwin;
    Window miniwin;
    size_t desk;
    int cx, cy, cw, ch;
    int x, y, w, h;
    int ishidden;
};

/* the pager */
struct Pager {
    struct Desktop **desktops;
    struct Client **clients;
    Window active;
    Window win;
    Pixmap pix;
    size_t nclients;
    size_t ndesktops;
    size_t currdesktop;
    int cellw, cellh;
    int w, h;
    int showingdesk;
};

/* configuration structure */
struct Config {
    int nrows, ncols;
    int x, y;
    int userplaced;
    int xnegative, ynegative;
    enum Orientation orient;
    enum StartingCorner corner;
    const char *windowcolors[STYLE_LAST][COLOR_LAST];
    const char *desktopselbg;
    const char *desktopbg;
    const char *separator;
};

/* global variables */
static XSetWindowAttributes miniswa = {
    .event_mask = ExposureMask | ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask
};
static int (*xerrorxlib)(Display *, XErrorEvent *);
static struct Pager pager = {0};
static struct DC dc;
static Atom atoms[ATOM_LAST];
static Display *dpy;
static Window root;
static Colormap colormap;
static unsigned int depth;
static int screen;
static int screenw, screenh;
static int wflag = 0;                   /* whether to start in withdrawn mode */
static int running = 1;

#include "config.h"

/* show usage and exit */
static void
usage(void)
{
    (void)fprintf(stderr, "usage: paginator [-w] [-c corner] [-g geometry] [-l layout] [-o orientation]\n");
    exit(1);
}

/* get maximum */
static int
max(int x, int y)
{
    return x > y ? x : y;
}

/* call malloc checking for error */
static void *
emalloc(size_t size)
{
    void *p;

    if ((p = malloc(size)) == NULL)
        err(1, "malloc");
    return p;
}

/* call calloc checking for errors */
static void *
ecalloc(size_t nmemb, size_t size)
{
    void *p;
    if ((p = calloc(nmemb, size)) == NULL)
        err(1, "calloc");
    return p;
}

/* get color from color string */
static unsigned long
ealloccolor(const char *s)
{
    XColor color;

    if(!XAllocNamedColor(dpy, colormap, s, &color, &color)) {
        warnx("could not allocate color: %s", s);
        return BlackPixel(dpy, screen);
    }
    return color.pixel;
}

/* error handler */
static int
xerror(Display *dpy, XErrorEvent *e)
{
    if (e->error_code == BadWindow || e->error_code == BadDrawable ||
        (e->request_code == X_ConfigureWindow && e->error_code == BadMatch) ||
        (e->request_code == X_ConfigureWindow && e->error_code == BadValue))
        return 0;

    errx(1, "Fatal request. Request code=%d, error code=%d", e->request_code, e->error_code);
    return xerrorxlib(dpy, e);
}

/* parse command-line options */
static void
getoptions(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ch;
    int status;
    char *s, *endp;

    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "c:g:l:o:w")) != -1) {
        switch (ch) {
        case 'c':
            if (strpbrk(optarg, "Bb") != NULL) {
                if (strpbrk(optarg, "Rr") != NULL) {
                    config.corner = _NET_WM_BOTTOMRIGHT;
                } else {
                    config.corner = _NET_WM_BOTTOMLEFT;
                }
            } else if (strpbrk(optarg, "Rr") != NULL) {
                config.corner = _NET_WM_TOPRIGHT;
            }
            break;
        case 'g':
            status = XParseGeometry(optarg, &config.x, &config.y, &pager.w, &pager.h);
            if (status & (XValue | YValue))
                config.userplaced = 1;
            if (status & XNegative)
                config.xnegative = 1;
            if (status & YNegative)
                config.ynegative = 1;
            break;
        case 'l':
            s = optarg;
            config.ncols = strtol(s, &endp, 10);
            if (config.ncols < 0 || config.ncols > MAX_DESKTOPS || endp == s)
                errx(1, "improper layout argument: %s", optarg);
            s = endp;
            if (*s != 'x' && *s != 'X')
                errx(1, "improper layout argument: %s", optarg);
            s++;
            config.nrows = strtol(s, &endp, 10);
            if (config.nrows < 0 || config.nrows > MAX_DESKTOPS || endp == s || *endp != '\0')
                errx(1, "improper layout argument: %s", optarg);
            break;
        case 'o':
            if (strpbrk(optarg, "Vv") != NULL)
                config.orient = _NET_WM_ORIENTATION_VERT;
            break;
        case 'w':
            wflag = 1;
            break;
        default:
            usage();
            break;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;
    if (argc != 0) {
        usage();
    }
}

/* get window property from root window; remember to XFree(wins) later */
static unsigned long
getwinprop(Window win, Atom prop, Window **wins)
{
    unsigned char *list;
    unsigned long len;
    unsigned long dl;   /* dummy variable */
    int di;             /* dummy variable */
    Atom da;            /* dummy variable */

    list = NULL;
    if (XGetWindowProperty(dpy, win, prop, 0L, 1024, False, XA_WINDOW, &da, &di, &len, &dl, &list) != Success || list == NULL) {
        *wins = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
    *wins = (Window *)list;
    return len;
}

/* get atom property from window */
static unsigned long
getcardprop(Window win, Atom prop)
{
    int di;
    unsigned long card;
    unsigned long dl;
    unsigned char *p = NULL;
    Atom da;

    card = 0;
    if (XGetWindowProperty(dpy, win, prop, 0L, 1024, False, XA_CARDINAL, &da, &di, &dl, &dl, &p) == Success && p) {
        card = *(unsigned long *)p;
        XFree(p);
    }
    return card;
}

/* get atom property from given window */
static unsigned long
getatomprop(Window win, Atom prop, Atom **atoms)
{
    unsigned char *list;
    unsigned long len;
    unsigned long dl;   /* dummy variable */
    int di;             /* dummy variable */
    Atom da;            /* dummy variable */

    list = NULL;
    if (XGetWindowProperty(dpy, win, prop, 0L, 1024, False, XA_ATOM,
                       &da, &di, &len, &dl, &list) != Success || list == NULL) {
        *atoms = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
    *atoms = (Atom *)list;
    return len;
}

/* return non-zero if window is hidden */
static int
ishidden(Window win)
{
    Atom *as;
    unsigned long natoms, i;
    int retval;

    retval = 0;
    if ((natoms = getatomprop(win, atoms[_NET_WM_STATE], &as)) != 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < natoms; i++) {
            if (as[i] == atoms[_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN]) {
                retval = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        XFree(as);
    }
    return retval;
}

/* send client message to root window */
static void
clientmsg(Window win, Atom atom, unsigned long d0, unsigned long d1, unsigned long d2, unsigned long d3, unsigned long d4)
{
    XEvent ev;
    long mask = SubstructureRedirectMask | SubstructureNotifyMask;

    ev.xclient.type = ClientMessage;
    ev.xclient.serial = 0;
    ev.xclient.send_event = True;
    ev.xclient.message_type = atom;
    ev.xclient.window = win;
    ev.xclient.format = 32;
    ev.xclient.data.l[0] = d0;
    ev.xclient.data.l[1] = d1;
    ev.xclient.data.l[2] = d2;
    ev.xclient.data.l[3] = d3;
    ev.xclient.data.l[4] = d4;
    if (!XSendEvent(dpy, root, False, mask, &ev)) {
        errx(1, "could not send event");
    }
}

/* free desktops and the desktop array */
static void
cleandesktops(void)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < pager.ndesktops; i++) {
        if (pager.desktops[i]->miniwin != None)
            XDestroyWindow(dpy, pager.desktops[i]->miniwin);
        free(pager.desktops[i]);
    }
    free(pager.desktops);
}

/* destroy client's mini-windows and free it */
static void
cleanclient(struct Client *cp)
{
    if (cp == NULL)
        return;
    if (cp->miniwin != None)
        XDestroyWindow(dpy, cp->miniwin);
    free(cp);
}

/* free clients and client array */
static void
cleanclients(void)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < pager.nclients; i++) {
        cleanclient(pager.clients[i]);
        pager.clients[i] = NULL;
    }
    free(pager.clients);
}

/* destroy drawing context */
static void
cleandc(void)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < STYLE_LAST; i++)
        XFreeColors(dpy, colormap, dc.windowcolors[i], COLOR_LAST, 0);
    XFreeColors(dpy, colormap, &dc.desktopselbg, 1, 0);
    XFreeColors(dpy, colormap, &dc.desktopbg, 1, 0);
    XFreeColors(dpy, colormap, &dc.separator, 1, 0);
    XFreeGC(dpy, dc.gc);
}

/* set pager size */
static void
setpagersize(int w, int h)
{
    pager.w = w;
    pager.h = h;
}

/* update number of desktops */
static void
setndesktops(void)
{
    size_t i;

    cleandesktops();
    pager.ndesktops = getcardprop(root, atoms[_NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS]);
    pager.desktops = ecalloc(pager.ndesktops, sizeof(*pager.desktops));
    if (pager.ndesktops < 1 || pager.ndesktops > MAX_DESKTOPS)
        errx(1, "could not get number of desktops");
    for (i = 0; i < pager.ndesktops; i++) {
        pager.desktops[i] = emalloc(sizeof(*pager.desktops[i]));
        pager.desktops[i]->miniwin = XCreateWindow(
            dpy, pager.win, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
            CopyFromParent, CopyFromParent, CopyFromParent,
            CWEventMask, &miniswa
        );
    }
}

/* search client list for a client for the given window */
static struct Client *
getclient(Window win)
{
    struct Client *cp;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < pager.nclients; i++) {
        if (pager.clients[i] != NULL && pager.clients[i]->clientwin == win) {
            cp = pager.clients[i];
            pager.clients[i] = NULL;
            return cp;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* update list of clients */
static void
setclients(void)
{
    struct Client **clients;
    Window *wins;
    Window dw;
    unsigned int du, b;
    size_t nclients;
    size_t i;
    int x, y;

    nclients = getwinprop(root, atoms[_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING], &wins);
    clients = ecalloc(nclients, sizeof(*clients));
    for (i = 0; i < nclients; i++) {
        if ((clients[i] = getclient(wins[i])) == NULL) {
            clients[i] = emalloc(sizeof(*clients[i]));
            clients[i]->clientwin = wins[i];
            XSelectInput(dpy, clients[i]->clientwin, StructureNotifyMask);
            clients[i]->miniwin = XCreateWindow(
                dpy, pager.win, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1,
                CopyFromParent, CopyFromParent, CopyFromParent,
                CWEventMask, &miniswa
            );
        }
        if (XGetGeometry(dpy, wins[i], &dw, &x, &y, &clients[i]->cw, &clients[i]->ch, &b, &du) &&
            XTranslateCoordinates(dpy, wins[i], root, x, y, &clients[i]->cx, &clients[i]->cy, &dw)) {
            clients[i]->ishidden = ishidden(clients[i]->clientwin);
            clients[i]->desk = getcardprop(clients[i]->clientwin, atoms[_NET_WM_DESKTOP]);
        } else {
            cleanclient(clients[i]);
            clients[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    cleanclients();
    pager.clients = clients;
    pager.nclients = nclients;
    XFree(wins);
}

/* set current desktop */
static void
setcurrdesktop(void)
{
    pager.currdesktop = getcardprop(root, atoms[_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP]);
    if (pager.currdesktop < 0) {
        errx(1, "could not get current desktop");
    }
}

/* update showing desktop state */
static void
setshowingdesk(void)
{
    pager.showingdesk = getcardprop(root, atoms[_NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP]);
}

/* set mini-desktops geometry */
static void
setdeskgeom(void)
{
    int x, y, w, h;
    size_t i, xi, yi;

    w = pager.w - config.ncols;
    h = pager.h - config.nrows;
    for (i = 0; i < pager.ndesktops; i++) {
        xi = yi = i;
        if (config.orient == _NET_WM_ORIENTATION_HORZ)
            yi /= config.ncols;
        else
            xi /= config.nrows;
        if (config.corner == _NET_WM_TOPRIGHT) {
            x = config.ncols - 1 - xi % config.ncols;
            y = yi % config.nrows;
        } else if (config.corner == _NET_WM_BOTTOMLEFT) {
            x = xi % config.ncols;
            y = config.nrows - 1 - yi % config.nrows;
        } else if (config.corner == _NET_WM_BOTTOMRIGHT) {
            x = config.ncols - 1 - xi % config.ncols;
            y = config.nrows - 1 - yi % config.nrows;
        } else {
            x = xi % config.ncols;
            y = yi % config.nrows;
        }
        pager.desktops[i]->x = w * x / config.ncols + x;
        pager.desktops[i]->y = h * y / config.nrows + y;
        pager.desktops[i]->w = max(1, w * (x + 1) / config.ncols - w * x / config.ncols);
        pager.desktops[i]->h = max(1, h * (y + 1) / config.nrows - h * y / config.nrows);
        XMoveResizeWindow(
            dpy, pager.desktops[i]->miniwin,
            pager.desktops[i]->x, pager.desktops[i]->y,
            pager.desktops[i]->w, pager.desktops[i]->h
        );
    }
}

/* set active window */
static void
setactive(void)
{
    Window *wins;

    pager.active = None;
    if (getwinprop(root, atoms[_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW], &wins) > 0) {
        pager.active = *wins;
        XFree(wins);
    }

}

/* map desktop miniwindows */
static void
mapdesktops(void)
{
    size_t i;
    unsigned long color;

    for (i = 0; i < pager.ndesktops; i++) {
        color = (i == pager.currdesktop) ? dc.desktopselbg : dc.desktopbg;
        XSetWindowBackground(dpy, pager.desktops[i]->miniwin, color);
        XSetForeground(dpy, dc.gc, color);
        XFillRectangle(dpy, pager.desktops[i]->miniwin, dc.gc, 0, 0, pager.desktops[i]->w, pager.desktops[i]->h);
        XMapWindow(dpy, pager.desktops[i]->miniwin);
    }
}

/* remap single client miniwindow */
static void
mapclient(struct Client *cp)
{
    struct Desktop *dp;
    int style;

    if (cp == NULL)
        return;
    style = (cp->clientwin == pager.active) ? STYLE_ACTIVE : STYLE_INACTIVE;
    XSetWindowBackground(dpy, cp->miniwin, dc.windowcolors[style][COLOR_BACKGROUND]);
    XSetWindowBorder(dpy, cp->miniwin, dc.windowcolors[style][COLOR_BORDER]);
    if (cp->ishidden || cp->desk < 0 || cp->desk >= pager.ndesktops) {
        XUnmapWindow(dpy, cp->miniwin);
    } else {
        dp = pager.desktops[cp->desk];
        cp->x = cp->cx * dp->w / screenw;
        cp->y = cp->cy * dp->h / screenh;
        cp->w = cp->cw * dp->w / screenw;
        cp->h = cp->ch * dp->h / screenh;
        XReparentWindow(dpy, cp->miniwin, dp->miniwin, cp->x, cp->y);
        XMoveResizeWindow(dpy, cp->miniwin, cp->x, cp->y, cp->w, cp->h);
        XMapWindow(dpy, cp->miniwin);
    }
}

/* remap all client miniwindows */
static void
mapclients(void)
{
    struct Client *cp;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < pager.nclients; i++) {
        cp = pager.clients[i];
        if (cp == NULL)
            continue;
        if (pager.showingdesk) {
            XUnmapWindow(dpy, cp->miniwin);
            continue;
        }
        mapclient(cp);
    }
}

/* draw pager pixmap */
static void
drawpager(void)
{
    int x, y;
    int w, h;
    int i;

    /* draw pager */
    if (pager.pix != None)
        XFreePixmap(dpy, pager.pix);
    pager.pix = XCreatePixmap(dpy, pager.win, pager.w, pager.h, depth);
    XSetForeground(dpy, dc.gc, dc.desktopbg);
    XFillRectangle(dpy, pager.pix, dc.gc, 0, 0, pager.w, pager.h);
    XSetForeground(dpy, dc.gc, dc.separator);
    w = pager.w - config.ncols;
    h = pager.h - config.nrows;
    for (i = 1; i < config.ncols; i++) {
        x = w * i / config.ncols + i - 1;
        XDrawLine(dpy, pager.pix, dc.gc, x, 0, x, pager.h);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < config.nrows; i++) {
        y = h * i / config.nrows + i - 1;
        XDrawLine(dpy, pager.pix, dc.gc, 0, y, pager.w, y);
    }
    XCopyArea(dpy, pager.pix, pager.win, dc.gc, 0, 0, pager.w, pager.h, 0, 0);
}

/* intern atoms */
static void
initatoms(void)
{
    char *atomnames[ATOM_LAST] = {
        [WM_DELETE_WINDOW]              = "WM_DELETE_WINDOW",
        [_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW]            = "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW",
        [_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING]     = "_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING",
        [_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP]          = "_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP",
        [_NET_WM_DESKTOP]               = "_NET_WM_DESKTOP",
        [_NET_DESKTOP_LAYOUT]           = "_NET_DESKTOP_LAYOUT",
        [_NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP]          = "_NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP",
        [_NET_MOVERESIZE_WINDOW]        = "_NET_MOVERESIZE_WINDOW",
        [_NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS]       = "_NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS",
        [_NET_WM_STATE]                 = "_NET_WM_STATE",
        [_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN]          = "_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN",
    };

    XInternAtoms(dpy, atomnames, ATOM_LAST, False, atoms);
}

/* initialize colors */
static void
initcolors(void)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < STYLE_LAST; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < COLOR_LAST; j++)
            dc.windowcolors[i][j] = ealloccolor(config.windowcolors[i][j]);
    dc.desktopselbg = ealloccolor(config.desktopselbg);
    dc.desktopbg = ealloccolor(config.desktopbg);
    dc.separator = ealloccolor(config.separator);
}

/* select events from root window */
static void
initroot(void)
{
    XChangeWindowAttributes(dpy, root, CWEventMask,
        &(XSetWindowAttributes){
            .event_mask = StructureNotifyMask | PropertyChangeMask,
        }
    );
}

/* compute prompt geometry and create prompt window */
static void
initpager(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    XWMHints *wmhints;
    XSizeHints *shints;
    XClassHint *chint;

    /* zero pager fields */
    pager.active = None;
    pager.pix = None;

    /* create pager window */
    pager.win = XCreateWindow(
        dpy, root, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
        CopyFromParent, CopyFromParent, CopyFromParent,
        CWEventMask | CWBackPixel,
        &(XSetWindowAttributes){
            .event_mask = ExposureMask | StructureNotifyMask,
            .background_pixel = dc.desktopbg,
        }
    );

    /* get initial number of desktops */
    setndesktops();
    setcurrdesktop();

    /* compute pager layout */
    if (config.ncols <= 0 && config.nrows <= 0)
        config.ncols = DEF_NCOLS;
    if (config.ncols > 0 && config.nrows <= 0)
        config.nrows = (pager.ndesktops + (pager.ndesktops % config.ncols)) / config.ncols;
    if (config.ncols <= 0 && config.nrows > 0)
        config.ncols = (pager.ndesktops + (pager.ndesktops % config.nrows)) / config.nrows;

    /* compute pager size */
    if (pager.w <= 0 && pager.h <= 0)
        pager.w = DEF_WIDTH;
    if (pager.w > 0 && pager.h <= 0)
        pager.h = SEPARATOR(config.nrows) + (config.nrows * (pager.w - SEPARATOR(config.ncols)) * screenh) / (config.ncols * screenw);
    if (pager.w <= 0 && pager.h > 0)
        pager.w = SEPARATOR(config.ncols) + (config.ncols * (pager.h - SEPARATOR(config.nrows)) * screenw) / (config.nrows * screenh);

    /* compute user-defined pager position */
    if (config.xnegative)
        config.x += screenw - pager.w;
    if (config.ynegative)
        config.y += screenh - pager.h;

    /* commit pager window geometry */
    XMoveResizeWindow(dpy, pager.win, config.x, config.y, pager.w, pager.h);

    /* create graphic contexts */
    dc.gc = XCreateGC(dpy, pager.win, GCFillStyle | GCLineStyle,
        &(XGCValues){
            .fill_style = FillSolid,
            .line_style = LineOnOffDash,
        }
    );

    /* set window hints */
    wmhints = NULL;
    if ((chint = XAllocClassHint()) == NULL)
        errx(1, "XAllocClassHint");
    chint->res_name = *argv;
    chint->res_class = PROGNAME;
    if ((shints = XAllocSizeHints()) == NULL)
        errx(1, "XAllocSizeHints");
    shints->flags = PMaxSize | PMinSize;
    if (config.userplaced)
        shints->flags |= USPosition;
    shints->min_width = shints->max_width = pager.w;
    shints->min_height = shints->max_height = pager.h;
    if (wflag) {
        if ((wmhints = XAllocWMHints()) == NULL)
            errx(1, "XAllocWMHints");
        wmhints->flags = IconWindowHint | StateHint;
        wmhints->initial_state = WithdrawnState;
        wmhints->icon_window = pager.win;
    }
    XmbSetWMProperties(dpy, pager.win, PROGNAME, PROGNAME, argv, argc, shints, wmhints, chint);
    XFree(chint);
    XFree(shints);
    XFree(wmhints);

    /* set WM protocols */
    XSetWMProtocols(dpy, pager.win, &atoms[WM_DELETE_WINDOW], 1);

    /* set window attributes */
    //XSetWindowBackground(dpy, pager.win, dc.desktopbg);

    /* get initial client list */
    setdeskgeom();
    setclients();
    setactive();
    drawpager();
    mapdesktops();
    mapclients();

    /* map window */
    XMapWindow(dpy, pager.win);
}

/* change current desktop to the one corresponding to the region under pointer */
static void
changedesk(Window win)
{
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < pager.ndesktops; i++) {
        if (win == pager.desktops[i]->miniwin) {
            clientmsg(None, atoms[_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP], i, CurrentTime, 0, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < pager.nclients; i++) {
        if (pager.clients[i] != NULL && win == pager.clients[i]->miniwin) {
            clientmsg(pager.clients[i]->clientwin, atoms[_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW], 2, CurrentTime, 0, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
}

/* handle button release events */
static void
xeventbuttonrelease(XEvent *e)
{
    XButtonEvent *ev;

    ev = &e->xbutton;
    if (ev->button == Button1) {
        changedesk(ev->window);
    }
}

/* handle client message events; basically the close window message */
static void
xeventclientmessage(XEvent *e)
{
    XClientMessageEvent *ev;

    ev = &e->xclient;
    if ((Atom)ev->data.l[0] == atoms[WM_DELETE_WINDOW]) {
        running = 0;
    }
}

/* handle configure notify events */
static void
xeventconfigurenotify(XEvent *e)
{
    XConfigureEvent *ev;
    size_t i;

    ev = &e->xconfigure;
    if (ev->window == root) {
        screenw = ev->width;
        screenh = ev->height;
    } else if (ev->window == pager.win) {
        setpagersize(ev->width, ev->height);
        setdeskgeom();
        drawpager();
        mapdesktops();
        mapclients();
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < pager.nclients; i++) {
            if (pager.clients[i] != NULL && ev->window == pager.clients[i]->clientwin) {
                mapclient(pager.clients[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

/* handle property notify events */
static void
xeventpropertynotify(XEvent *e)
{
    XPropertyEvent *ev;

    ev = &e->xproperty;
    if (ev->atom == atoms[_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING]) {
        setclients();
        mapclients();
    } else if (ev->atom == atoms[_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW]) {
        setactive();
        mapclients();
    } else if (ev->atom == atoms[_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP]) {
        setcurrdesktop();
        mapdesktops();
    } else if (ev->atom == atoms[_NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP]) {
        setshowingdesk();
        mapclients();
    } else if (ev->atom == atoms[_NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS]) {
        setndesktops();
        drawpager();
        mapdesktops();
    } else if (ev->atom == atoms[_NET_WM_STATE]) {
        // TODO
    } else if (ev->atom == atoms[_NET_WM_DESKTOP]) {
        // TODO
    }
}

/* handle expose events */
static void
xeventexpose(XEvent *e)
{
    XExposeEvent *ev;

    ev = &e->xexpose;
    if (ev->window == pager.win) {
        XCopyArea(dpy, pager.pix, pager.win, dc.gc, 0, 0, pager.w, pager.h, 0, 0);
    }
}

/* paginator: a X11 desktop pager */
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    XEvent ev;
    void (*xevents[LASTEvent])(XEvent *) = {
        [Expose]                = xeventexpose,
        [ButtonRelease]         = xeventbuttonrelease,
        [ConfigureNotify]       = xeventconfigurenotify,
        [ClientMessage]         = xeventclientmessage,
        [PropertyNotify]        = xeventpropertynotify,
    };

    if ((dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL)) == NULL)
        errx(1, "could not open display");
    screen = DefaultScreen(dpy);
    root = RootWindow(dpy, screen);
    colormap = DefaultColormap(dpy, screen);
    depth = DefaultDepth(dpy, screen);
    screenw = DisplayWidth(dpy, screen);
    screenh = DisplayHeight(dpy, screen);
    xerrorxlib = XSetErrorHandler(xerror);
    getoptions(argc, argv);
    initatoms();
    initcolors();
    initroot();
    initpager(argc, argv);
    while (running && !XNextEvent(dpy, &ev))
        if (xevents[ev.type] != NULL)
            (*xevents[ev.type])(&ev);
    cleandesktops();
    cleanclients();
    cleandc();
    XCloseDisplay(dpy);
    return 0;
}
```

To compile, use the following commands:

```sh
cc -g -O0 -Wall -Wextra -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/X11R6/include  -c paginator.c
cc -o paginator paginator.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11
```